# ansbile gather_facts module missing ansble_* in front

Tags: ansible

The ansible gather facts (setup) module isn't returning the ansible_architecture var rather it just returns architecture.  Without the ansible_, I can't use the facts in my playbooks. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

I can't say 'why', but you can set it by yourself if you need it in the role:

```
pre_tasks:
  - name: Defining ansible_achitecture
    set_fact:
      ansible_achitecture: '{{ architecture }}'
```